# Read & Remove files containing space in its name

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I have to read the list of file names from file A.txt,Where the file names has space in it,So can't able remove.File A.txt is given below

```
20150726140135_Content 1.mp4
20150726162955_Content 1.mp4
20150726163056_Content 3.mp4
20150726164057_Content 5.mp4
20150726170315_Tab main 2.mp4

for f in $(cat A.txt) ; do 
   rm "/tmp/$f";
done
```

While try this the file breaking into two which causes the error

```
rm: cannot remove `/tmp/20150726170315_Tab': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove `/tmp/2': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> for i in $(cat)

is a common antipattern in bash. You should not use a for loop to read lines. This doesn't work because:

1. First `$(cat A.txt)` is expanded to `20150726140135_Content 1.mp4
   20150726162955_Content 1.mp4
   20150726163056_Content 3.mp4
   20150726164057_Content 5.mp4
   20150726170315_Tab main 2.mp4` (no quotes).
2. Then shell executes the command `for i in 20150726140135_Content 1.mp4 20150726162955_Content 1.mp4 20150726163056_Content 3.mp4
   20150726164057_Content 5.mp4 20150726170315_Tab main 2.mp4`. Newlines and spaces are intepreted as arguments separators.

To [read a file line by line in bash](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) use a `while IFS= read -r` loop:

```
while IFS= read -r f; do 
   rm "/tmp/$f";
done < A.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use xargs. The -I' will use line based input.

```
xargs -i{} rm /tmp/{} < file.txt
```

Comment: I think that would be `/tmp/{}`. And maybe with `-d$'\n'` as `xargs` by default interprets quotes, so if a filename has quotes it will fail.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to remove files starting with 2015 or any other pattern

```
while IFS='\s' read -r f; do 
   rm $f*;
done
```

Comment: There are at least 4 things wrong with this answer. `IFS` takes a literal list of characters, not a pattern. `\s` isn't a pattern representing a space in `bash`. The only purpose of setting `IFS` is to specify how to split the input line, but `read` won't do any splitting because it has only one argument. And once you *do* have a file name in `f`, leaving `$f` unquoted just repeats the same problem with word-splitting.